# Proving that $d(x_n,y_n) < \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This is my first time posting a question on this website so I apologize if I'm doing anything wrong.

I am trying to prove that $d(x_n,y_n) < \varepsilon$ given that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are sequences that are Cauchy. 
Note that I am NOT trying to prove $d(x_n,y_n)$ converges to $d(x,y)$, and that I have already looked into this.

What I know:

- I know that given $x_n$ and $y_n$ are cauchy, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $m$, $n > N$ implies that $|x_n - x_m| < \varepsilon$ and $|y_n - y_m| < \varepsilon$.
- I am assuming the triangle inequality somehow comes into play here but I am not sure how.

What I am given:

- $x_n$ converges to $x$
- $x_n$ and $y_n$ are mutually Cauchy, meaning that their alternation $x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, x_3, y_3,\ldots$ is Cauchy

I am just looking for hints/helpful advice!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know anything more than $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ being Cauchy you cannot prove. It is simply false.For example the sequences could be two different constant sequences.

Edit: If you know that $(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,...)$ is Cauchy (as mentioned in your comment then the sequence $(z_n)$ defined by $z_n=y_{n/2}$ for $n$ even and $z_n=x_{(n+1)/2}$ for $n$ odd is  Cauchy. So $d(z_{2n},z_{2n-1})<\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large. And this inequality says $d(y_n,x_n) <\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: I forgot to add that I am also given that they are mutually Cauchy, meaning that the alternation x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, ... is Cauchy although I do not know if that would help. I also forgot to mention that I am given that xn converges to x.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense.